# PHP library to manage database definitions?

Tags: php, database-schema

I'm looking for a convenient way of storing and managing SQL-table definitions in an application, mostly to make installation easier.

I could just hard code an "install.php" full of `CREATE TABLE`, but I figure there are nicer alternatives.

Comment: Why not just a `schema.sql`? It's not particularly difficult to parse (assuming it's only `CREATE TABLE`s) and the parser can map the schema to the appropriate DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

One answer I've found myself is [Doctrines ORM](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html) which appears to have a this capability. Would like to hear about other options as well.